# Wrapping a concurrent collection

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a class where I'm wrapping Java's `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` collection. I have a method called `addToQueue` that takes a value and inserts that value into the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. Does it matter that my method is not synchronized? My understanding is that it doesn't matter since the collection itself is concurrent. Multiple threads should be able call my `addToQueue` method.

Comment: if you just call one method in your wrapped list, then no, you don't have to synchronize it. but if you call several, for example `if (list.size() < 3) {list.add(obj);}` then you have to synchronize that bloc (consider 2 threads entering, it is possible to add more than 3 items.)